# SQL - INSERT SELECT two columns without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, subquery, insert-select

I am trying to do two subqueries to populate my table with two columns. `wk_start` and `wk_end`.
Goal is to populate it with a specific range of `date`.

I've tried cross join but still having duplicates the same as this one

Here is my code

```
insert into bfs_dw.mpt_calendar (wk_start, wk_end)

select 

ter.wk_start,
ter1.wk_end

from

(select * from 
(select ADDDATE('2022-01-03', 7*(t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) wk_start from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where wk_start < '2024-01-03'
order by wk_start ) ter

inner JOIN 

(select * from 
(select ADDDATE('2022-01-09', 7*(t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) wk_end from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where wk_end < '2024-01-03'
order by wk_end ) ter1 ON 1 = 1
```

Output display below. which has a lot of duplicates after the insert.

[image]

What I am trying to do is this expected result, which has no duplicates once inserted:

[image]

Note: the two subqueries works well. Its output was the last image posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first subquery to get `wk_start`, and add 6 days to get the `wk_end`

```
insert into bfs_dw.mpt_calendar (wk_start, wk_end)

select wk_start, wk_start + INTERVAL 6 DAY wk_end from 
(select ADDDATE('2022-01-03', 7*(t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) wk_start from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where wk_start < '2024-01-03'
```

Comment: Awesome! never thought that I can use the wk_start subquery to get wk_end. Thanks ProGu!